# Error #1370 while importing mysql database on a host

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import my database on a web-host and I'm getting this error: **#1370 - alter routine command denied to user 'epiz_24327314'@'192.168.%' for routine 'epiz_24327314_p4c.define_task_result'**

I tried deleting the lines "create database.." from my sql file and granting privileges to my remote account (which I used to create **epiz_24327314_p4c** database where I'm trying to import) but it solved nothing.

Here are the first lines of my sql file:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Creato il: Ago 14, 2019 alle 13:03
-- Versione del server: 5.7.17
-- Versione PHP: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `p4c`
--

DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedure
--
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `define_task_result`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `define_task_result` (IN `_task_id` INT, IN `count_answers` INT)  BEGIN
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: maybe adding `grant execute on db.* to root@localhost;`

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory. User associated to the database doesn't have required privileges. Give the MySQL user associated to the database **execute** permissions. Or modify the SQL file and put the unnecessary MySQL queries out of the file. But if they are mandatory, you will have to use a user with required privileges:

```sql
grant execute on epiz_24327314_p4c.* to epiz_24327314@localhost;
```

Comment: Is it possible that when I'm executing the query **GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON epiz_24327314_p4c . * TO 'epiz_24327314'@'sql113.epizy.com'** I'm getting error **#1044 - Access denied for user 'epiz_24327314'@'192.168.%' to database 'epiz_24327314_p4c'**? Could this possibly be a host problem?

Comment: @dl_ no, you need to be a higher authority to grant privileges to that user. Log in as MySQL `root` user.

Comment: You need to contact the system admin to get this fixed for you. Looks like this file was exported using root privileges. Without having higher privileges, you will not be able to import this file. If you are expert enough, you may exclude unnecessary queries out of the file, but if they are crucial ones, you will not be able to get this working. So your best bet is to import the SQL file with a user that has the necessary permissions.

Comment: @Martin how can I log in as a root on a remote host with phpMyAdmin? My current user is epiz_24327314 and I don't know if I can change it

Comment: From where did you create that user? And if you are using a shared host, you will not have the root access.

Comment: @Rehmat I created that user from host c-panel.. Apparently you were right and the only way to solve this is to contact the host support